# How do I add SAP Gateway services to an existing SAP WEB IDE Project?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I've imported a SAP WEB IDE project from SAP Build....

All looks great, but now I need to add in my Gateway services to handle oData etc.

I've setup my SAP Cloud Connector to and Destinations.

How specifically do I add these as all tutorials seems to start by including the service as part of a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do some steps to make this work:

1. implement the service definition in your manifest.json file:

   ```
   "sap.app": {
    [...],
    "dataSources": {
       "mainService": {
           "uri": "/your/path/to/service",
           "type": "OData",
           "settings": {
               "odataVersion": "2.0",
               "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
           }
       }
   },
   [...]
   ```

   },
2. implement the model definition in your manifest.json file:

   ```
   "models": {
       [...],
       "": {
           "dataSource": "mainService",
           "settings": {
               "metadataUrlParams": {
                   "sap-documentation": "heading"
               },
               "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay"
           }
       }
   },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the New>oData service menu from the project and create it that way too.